# Is using takeUntil() more preferable than unsubscribe() in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I've been researching the topic regarding unsubscribing in Angular(Observables/RxJs), where there are several ways to do that: takeUntil/takeWhile/unsubscribe. And based on my observations, most of the articles/answers recommend using takeUntil approach.
Therefore, there's the following question.. Is takeUntil really the preferred unsubscribe method to follow? if so, what are its advantages over unsubscribe?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends how many subscriptions you have. With take until you can manage many subscriptions with a single subject. If you have a single subscription then use a subscription with an unsubscribe unless you really want consistency with your pattern.

That being said the preferred solution is to not subscribe in the TypeScript class at all and use the async pipe in the template.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data">{{ data | json }}</ng-container>
```

or

```
<my-component [data]="data$ | async"></my-component>
```

This way the subscriptions are managed for you.

Comment: Great answer!

Personally, I've adopted the convention of just always using takeUntil, even for just one subscription.